# UNWIND feature in py2neo not reading json fully

Tags: python, json, graph, neo4j, py2neo

```
graph = Graph()
query2 = """
WITH {m} AS document
UNWIND document.lists AS s
UNWIND s.imageurl AS img
UNWIND s.youtubevideourl AS vid
RETURN s
"""
print (graph.cypher.execute(query2,m = m))
```

I am trying to use UNWIND to read through the full json file but I am only

getting through the first part and so I am unable to plot a graph of full json.

It was working fine earlier but now I have added youtube video links, title of

same page, weblinkurl, webtitle I have started facing the same problem.

Here is an example of JSON file I compiled with different links as I am able to read first part only but I want to read full JSON.

This has only 2 parts of JSON and I want to read full and make nodes

Please if anyone could tell how to do using UNWIND or else.

```
[{'Topic': 'Virat_Kohli',
  'imagetitle': 'Virat_Kohli_June_2016_(cropped).jpg?width=300',
  'imageurl': 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Virat_Kohli_June_2016_(cropped).jpg?width=300',
  'webtitle': 'Virat Kohli Official Website',
  'weburl': 'http://www.viratkohli.club/',
  'youtubevideotitle': 'Virat Kohli Finally Accepts Love For GIRLFRIEND Anushka Sharma On Aamir Khan&#39;s Secret Superstar Show - YouTube',
  'youtubevideourl': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmPh2OQzZqc'},
 {'Topic': 'Virat_Kohli',
  'webtitle': 'Virat Kohli profile 2017, News and images only on official website of RCB',
  'weburl': 'https://www.royalchallengers.com/virat-kohli',
  'youtubevideotitle': 'Virat Kohli after losing ICC champions trophy Final - India vs Pakistian - Press Conference 2017 - YouTube',
  'youtubevideourl': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yf38l1Kx2-I'},
```

what i am trying is to do is this

```
graph = Graph()
query2 = """
WITH {j} AS document
UNWIND document.lists AS s
UNWIND s.Topic AS  top
UNWIND s.weburl AS  url
UNWIND s.imageurl AS  img
UNWIND s.youtubevideourl as y
MERGE (c:topicnames {name:s.Topic})
MERGE (sc:images{img:img, type : s.imagetitle})
MERGE (v:weblink{url:url, type : s.webtitle})
MERGE (g:videos{vid:y, type : s.youtubevideotitle})
MERGE (c)-[:IMAGE_LINKS]->(sc)
MERGE (c)-[:WEB_LINKS]->(v)
MERGE (c)-[:VIDEO_LINKS]->(g)
RETURN (c)
"""


print (graph.cypher.execute(query2,j = j))
```

So I must have a single node of topic and 5 video link nodes, 5 weblink nodes and 1 imagelink node in  neo4j but its only drawing nodes for 1 part of json
so UNWIND is not reading or converting other values having same key as Topic, weburl,youtubevideourl  and that is why I want to know why its not working and how to fix it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the 3 `UNWINDS`? You query is only returning `s`, which is obtained by the first `UNWIND`.

Comment: I think you may not understand what UNWIND does. UNWIND operates on a collection/list, and changes that collection into rows. The first UNWIND looks fine, but the other two are operating on non-collection values (they are strings according to your excerpt). What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: what i want to do

Comment: #InverseFalcon # cybersam  please read the question as I have updated it

Comment: I am getting it in form of a dict here I have only shown the value inside the dict   it is like this

Comment: I am getting it in form of a dict here I have only shown the value inside the dict   it is like this                                                                                               {'lists': [{''Topic': 'Virat_Kohli', 'imagetitle':}]}         I am UNWINDING the dict as document to get values inside.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file itself is the list of documents so you don't need to specifically pass a list. And you don't need to use UNWIND that many times. Try using below program(And make sure all the variables are present when parsing):

```
graph = Graph()
query2 = """
UNWIND {j} AS s
MERGE (c:topicnames {name:s.Topic})
MERGE (sc:images{img:s.imageurl, type : s.imagetitle})
MERGE (v:weblink{url:s.weburl, type : s.webtitle})
MERGE (g:videos{vid:s.youtubevideourl, type : s.youtubevideotitle})
MERGE (c)-[:IMAGE_LINKS]->(sc)
MERGE (c)-[:WEB_LINKS]->(v)
MERGE (c)-[:VIDEO_LINKS]->(g)
RETURN (c)
"""
print (graph.cypher.execute(query2,j = j))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the same but it gives semantic error .-AttributeError: module 'py2neo.cypher. 'SemanticError'.  still thanks for your advice

Comment: why don't you try python-neo4j driver. it is faster and easier than py2neo. I'm advising this because we are using the driver in our current projects.